# Multiple (almost) flag-worthy qualities on one question

Tags: discussion, flags

Today I came across a question that had several issues. It was *almost* a duplicate, *almost* not a real question, *almost* too localized, and a give-me-teh-codez question. It didn't display any of these qualities to an extent that any individual issue was flag-worthy. It also wasn't so extremely low-quality that it couldn't (theoretically) be saved by (extremely extensive) editing. 
[image]
What should I do when I come across this kind of question? I hate feeling like I'm spamming the flag queue.

Comment: I have to ask, what was the question? It's a bit difficult to answer without a practical example. Though perhaps it's very low quality as a result of all these issues? Perhaps a custom flag would have been appropriate? If it gets rejected, no harm done.

Comment: @Bart Right, I was looking for a generic answer but I'll add an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're being far too kind with your flagging behavior. The particular example only seems to have some code dumped into the question to avoid the "show us your code" question. I would have voted to close this as "not a real question".

In general though, should you encounter a question with various issues (which you can't address in an edit) a "very low quality" flag or perhaps a custom flag message might be appropriate. That is, if none of the other flags apply, but it's still a bad question. The worst thing that can happen to you is that it gets rejected.

Comment: Haha, that's what I thought - didn't even bother to write `UITableView` correctly.