# How to Flag a Post Having Multiple Issues?

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple (almost) flag-worthy qualities on one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142675/multiple-almost-flag-worthy-qualities-on-one-question)

The other day I came across a post having multiple issues. The post appeared to have been copied verbatim from another site without attribution, and the voting on that post and others by that user seemed very sockpuppet-ish.

I tried to explain both concerns in a flag (though I admittedly did a poor job of it). And the flag was marked helpful and the post deleted.

The post was subsequently undeleted when attribution was added.

The feedback problem with this scenario is that then I don't know whether one concern was deemed helpful and the other dismissed, I didn't make my second point clearly enough, or whether it just takes longer to deal with.

The resolution to this earlier question was that one should add a custom flag message. I'm wondering if there's perhaps a better way to know whether each point was considered helpful so one doesn't have to feel inclined to toss even more flags if the issue doesn't appear to be resolved right away.

[Multiple (almost) flag-worthy qualities on one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142675/multiple-almost-flag-worthy-qualities-on-one-question)

Comment: There is no real way to see what part was acknowledged or not. Just keep an eye on the situation. Especially with regards to sockpuppets, if you keep seeing something suspicious, perhaps flag another contribution just for this. But even that, if marked helpful, does not necessarily mean you were right.

Comment: Too much of an edge-case for a feature request too I know.  I just hate being a pain in the butt :)

Comment: Too late for that. ;)

Comment: Can you link to the post you flagged?

Comment: #Bart Bahahaha, I know. :D

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386375/having-problems-using-iis-express-ssl-with-vs2012-and-a-team/13553298#13553298) (It's already got a second helpful response FWIW. And I should have been less vague about my concern in the initial flag, but I always feel like my reason has to fit in the itty bitty text box even though I know that isn't the case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only flag a post once.

But with the custom flag message, you can use any text you like to make your point.

Comment: up to 500 characters...

Comment: If you need more than 500 characters, it must be obvious why to delete the post.